# Toggle Push Nav. But won't push main content when I open menu (No Jquery)

Tags: javascript

```
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Services</a>
<a href="#">Clients</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
<span class="menuBtn" onclick="toggleNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>

<script>
function toggleNav() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
var y = document.getElementById("main");
  if (x.style.width === "") {
    x.style.width = "250px"
    y.style.marginLeft = "250px"
} else {
    x.style.width = "";
    y.style.marginLeft = "";
}

}
</script>
</body>
```

I am trying to push the main content to one side when I open the nav menu. Trying to accomplish this with one button only. I am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function toggleNav() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySideNav");
      var y = document.getElementById("main");
      var width = x.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      
      y.classList.toggle('open');
      
      if (y.classList.contains('open')){
        x.style.left = '0px';
        y.style.left = width + 'px';
      } else {
        x.style.left = -width + 'px';
        y.style.left = '0px';
      }

    }
```

```css
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .menuBtn:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mySideNav {
      position: absolute;
      left: -300px;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transition: all 1s;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: lightblue;
     }

    #main {
      background-color: lightgreen;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      transition: all 1s;
    }

    .open {
      background-color: rgb(100, 200, 255) !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="mySideNav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <span class="menuBtn" onclick="toggleNav()">
        &#9776;
      </span>
      <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </div>
```

**Edit:** Alright, it is no longer Friday and I am feeling less lazy today.  This now works no matter what size the side nav is set to.

Comment: If you wanted to improve my answer, you could have the function calculate the width that the elements move over at run time.  It will be much easier to maintain this way, I was just lazy.

Comment: Great answer, I can take it from here. Just don't be lazy